# Java: having a collection of items, where each item has a field "previousItem", what is the most efficient way to order the collection?

Tags: java, collections, hierarchical-data

I have a collection of hierarchical items in an unsorted collection. Each of these items has a field previousItem:

```
public class Item{
   public Item previousItem;
}
```

What is the most efficient way of processing these items so that the output is a collection, where the Item without any previousItem is the first Item in the collection and each subesequent item's previousItem is the previous item in the collection?

My first idea would be to implement the Comparable interface in the Item class:

```
public int compareTo(Item that) {
    final int BEFORE = -1;
    final int EQUAL = 0;
    final int AFTER = 1;

    if(this.previousItem==null){
        return BEFORE;
    }

    if(that.previousItem==null){
        return AFTER;
    }

    if(this.previousItem.equals(that){
        return AFTER;
    }else if(that.previousItem.equals(this){
        return BEFORE;
    }

    return EQUAL;
}
```

and then loop through the items an add them to a TreeSet:

```
SortedSet<Item> itemSortedSet = new TreeSet<Item>();
for (Item item : itemCollection) {
    itemSortedSet.add(item);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way (less time to process/number of iterations needed) to order the collection so that they are in logical, hierarchical order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your comparator would not work: it does not provide transitivity, i.e. it will do the wrong thing if you compare items A and C in the case of A->B->C.

If no items can have the *same* previous item, your `Item` objects essentially form a basic linked list. If you happen to know which one is that last item, you can start from there with a single loop and unravel the whole structure:

```
Item last = ...;

while (last != null) {
    result.add(last)
    last = last.previousItem
}
```

If you do not have a way to find out which item is the last one, then you could use an [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) to map each `previousItem` value to the `Item` object that uses it:

```
IdentityHashMap<Item,Item> m = new IdentityHashMap<Item,Item>(itemset.size());

for (Item i : itemset)
    m.put(i.previousItem, i);

Item i = m.get(null);

while (i != null) {
    result.add(i);

    i = m.get(i);
}
```

This will unravel your unsorted collection starting from the item that has no previous node.

Both methods have a roughly linear complexity w.r.t. the number of items, but they make two assumptions that may not be valid in your case:

- That each item can only be the previous item of at most *one* other node, i.e. that your items are a list instead of a tree.
- That there is a single "thread" of items.

If either of these assumptions is not valid you will need a far more complex algorithm to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your Item is already implementing a linked-list (if not by name), so the natural (for me) way to put it in a collection is to transform it into a real list recursively. After the items are transformed, you may need to reverse the list, according to your specification.

```
public class Item {
   Item previousItem;

   public void putToCollection(ArrayList<Item> list) {
     list.add(this);
     if (previousItem == null) {
       Collections.reverse(list);
     } else {
       previousItem.putToCollection(list);
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a handle on the Item object without previous object. You could just loop through the Items (e.g. with a while-loop) and add them to an ArrayList or a LinkedList, because the add()-Method of those List implementations just appends a new Item at the end of the list. This way, you get through it in O(n)-time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HashSet<Item>` in which you initially put all the items. Then you go over the items in a loop and remove every `previousItem` from your set. At the end you should be left with a single element in the set, the last one, which was not a `previousItem` for any other item. And then you can simply add items starting from that one and going through the links.